# NoSuchAlgorithmException when launching JNLP with Java 7

Tags: java, runtime-error, java-7, jnlp, java-web-start

After upgrading to Java 7, when launching remote jnlp, I see the following exception in the Java console:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: WIExplorerMy not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.services.WPlatformService$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.services.WPlatformService.getBrowserClientAuthKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.context.InitialJNLPExecutionContext.getBrowserClientAuthKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.DisconnectedExecutionContext.getBrowserClientAuthKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2BrowserService.getBrowserClientAuthKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509DeployKeyManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.https.Handler$Initializer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.https.Handler$Initializer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.createUrlConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: WIExplorerMy KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

In addition the error screen saying "Error. Click for details" appears for about 2 seconds and disappears afterwards.

Other then that, everything seems to function normally.

With Java 6 everything works as expected.

Ideas how to fix it?

Comment: *"Ideas?"*  1) Check the bug DB. 2) If nothing found, raise a new one. 3) Ask more specific questions on SO.

Comment: 1 and 2) will do 
3) What details do you miss?

Comment: A specific question might be "Is this a bug in my code or the JRE?"  or  "How to fix this run-time exception?"..

Comment: Ok, fixed the title. Is it better now?

Comment: I see the same exception using Netbeans 7.4 (dev build) IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the latest Java 7 updates have obsoleted some encryption schemes, so that would be a completely normal exception to get **if you were using one of these while using Java 6**.

See this [list of enhancements and changes for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html):

> **Weak cipher suites deprecated**
>
> Per RFC 4346, RFC 5246, and RFC 5469, some cipher suites have been made obsolete and should not be used. These obsolete suites are all disabled by default in SunJSSE. For details, consult the cipher suite lists in the documentation about the SunJSSE provider.

That being said, that would explain the NoSuchAlgorithmException, but the error message seems to mention something about a missing keystore, so this may be unrelated and we woud need you to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or anything close enough to one.

Comment: Thanks for the point about the exception. I'll check which cipher is used. I'll also try to provide the SSCCE, it may be a little difficult with SSL, but maybe I'll create something with selfsigned certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding

```
security.provider.11=com.sun.deploy.security.MSCryptoProvider
```

to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\java.security`

Although the error wasn't fatal for me, it is just the javaws trying to read the local browser key store before falling back to the java keystores that are managed by the control panel. Those files are in `C:\Users\USERID\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security`

Interestingly there is a security provider that comes pre-wired into the java.security file, and it is

```
security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

This provider can also read the browser keystore, but the store type is windows-my, and not WIExplorerMy

Answer (score 0):

Tarlog, do you have any resolution found yet? I have the same problem, I am suspecting that the first problem with KeyStoreException exception only happens if you are trying secure connection. And that sinister "Error. Click for details" issue happens on any Applet loaded through an jnlp.

I could not find any resolution yet.

Edit: For the KeyStoreException I have realised that the problem occured due to apache certificate files were gone somehow. I have generated ceritificate files and restarted apache. The exception no longer occurs.

The other problem with Error window still exists.

Comment: Found nothing yet. opened a bug #9002620 on  http://bugs.sun.com but it wasn't reviewed yet.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report reference/

Comment: I cannot find 9002620 on bugs.sun.com yet. Do you have any progress?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the `Error Click for details issue` – I resolved this by adding a class to the source that implements `javax.jnlp.DownloadServiceListener` (can just be a dummy class) and then specifying that class in your jnlp file `(applet-desc/@progress-class="YourClass")`